# How to run a portable Jar-File in Java 20 (OpenJDK 20)

Tags: java, jar, portability, java-20

I would like to run a portable jar-file created with OpenJDK 20  (i.e. without installation).

So far I have managed this with the OpenJDKJRE package for Java 14 from portableapps.com. But for the OpenJDK 20 I don't know where to get the JRE. Does anyone have an idea where to get it?

Comment: Doesn't the JDK include a JRE?

Comment: The proper method would be to use jlink or jpackage to create a suitable custom JRE specifically for your application.

Comment: ah ok thanks for the tip, i'll take a closer look.

Comment: There is no need to get a JDK or JRE from portableapps.com. Their definition of “portable”, i.e. “can be used from an arbitrary filesystem location”, applies to the JDK/JRE by default. Just download a JDK or JRE as zip folder and extract it to wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly the JDK already includes the JRE, so you should be fine if you install the latest JDK 20.